# Grouping of data

Tags: sql, group-by, ms-access-2007

I have a database that records clients who have a rating score upon entry of the service we provide, this is between 0 - 50, they are seen on average once a week and after four sessions they are re-evaluated on the same score to see a trend so say initially they may score 22 and after four weeks it may be 44
What i am after is a sql query to group this data

```
+----+-------+--------+
|name|initial|followup|
+----+-------+--------+
|joe |22     |        |
+----+-------+--------+
|joe |       |44      |
+----+-------+--------+
```

i want this to show

```
+----+-------+--------+
|name|initial|followup|
+----+-------+--------+
|joe |22     |44      |
+----+-------+--------+
```

i know this is a simple question and have done this before but tis the time of the year and the pressure is on from management 
many thanks in advance

Comment: Is this how your table is structured? Your table has 3 fields? Name, initial, followup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `-` means `NULL`, just use aggregation:

```
select name, max(initial) as initial, max(followup) as followup
from t
group by name;
```